# Custom ListView from SQLite Cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, spinner, android-adapter

My list contains elements with *name* and *status*. The name is a `String` and the *status* is an `int`.
I want to have a `ListView` where each element shows the *name* and a drop-down for selecting the *status*. Also, the background color will change based on the *status* `int`.

[image: ListView]
I have the Cursor:

```
String[] ItemsData= { "id", "name", "status" };

Cursor ItemsCursor = ItemsDatabase.query(
    Database.ITEMS_TABLE, ItemsData, null, null, null, null, null
);

ItemsCursor.moveToFirst();
```

and I have created the list (programmatically is how I must do it):

```
ListView ItemsListView = new ListView(this);
```

Now, I know that I can use and `Adapter` (like `SimpleCursorAdapter`) but I don't know how to do it, taking into account that the `name` is a `String` inside a `TextView` and the *status* is a `Spinner` with predefined values saved as `int` in the database, with the default value being the one corresponding to the *status*. Also, the *status* changes the background color, too.

Maybe I can't use an `Adapter`. Also, I don't know how to include a `Spinner` inside each list element, if possible.

Comment: You should create the items for the *ListView* in *xaml*. [This](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) tutorial may help you

Comment: I can anticipate the complexity of having a adapter inflated DropDown for each row of a list view. I would rather suggest a Dialog that holds the dropDown to appear on tap of individual list elements.

Comment: Right, I will place a button that must contain the text corresponding to each status number. But, how do I make the `Cursor` convert the number to a `String` before binding it to the `ListView`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i do it :

```
listV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.viewTest);
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listItem = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

int     i = 1;
String  value = null;
HashMap<String, String> map;
while ((value = database.getStuff(i)) != null) {
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("title", value);
        map.put("desc", "RANDOM TEXT");
        map.put("img", String.valueOf(R.drawable.images));
        listItem.add(map);
        i++;
    }

    SimpleAdapter s = new SimpleAdapter (this.getBaseContext(), listItem, R.layout.list_content,
            new String[] {"img", "title", "desc"}, new int[] {R.id.img, R.id.stuff, R.id.stuff});
    listV.setAdapter(s);
```

And here is where i deal with the cursors :

```
public String getStuff(int id) {
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT value FROM test WHERE _id = " +id, null);
    return cursorToString(c);
}

private String cursorToString(Cursor c) {
    if (c.getCount() == 0)
        return null;
    c.moveToFirst();
    String s = c.getString(0);
    c.close();
    return s;
}
```

The "R.layout.list_content" is the .xml file used to setup the shape of each item of your list, you can add images TextView and everything else you want !

Just tell me if you want more infos about the .xml stuff

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CursorAdapter to build the rows from any layout you want.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c, false);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // Populate view with the cursor, add listeners...
    }
}
```